# Plot the symmetric part of a graph that was obtained from a data table

Tags: plotting

This is half of a leaf:

```
y = Table[(1.1)^73 ((j - 1)/149), {j, 150}];
x1to45 = Table[(1 + 0.1/1.5 (1 - ((45 - j)/(45 - 1))^2.5))^73, {j, 
45}];
x46to150 = Table[(1 + 0.1/1.5 (1 - ((j - 45)/(150 - 45))^2.5))^73, {j, 46, 
150}];
x = Join[x1to45, x46to150];
xy = ListLinePlot[Transpose[Flatten /@ {x, y}]]
```

I need to graph the entire leaf. I tried it as follows:

```
nx1to45 = Table[2 - (1 + 0.1/1.5 (1 - ((45 -   j)/(45 - 1))^2.5))^73, {j, 45}];
nx46to150 = Table[2 - (1 + 0.1/1.5 (1 - ((j - 45)/(150 - 45))^2.5))^73, {j, 46, 
150}];
nx = Join[nx1to45, nx46to150];
nxy = ListLinePlot[Transpose[Flatten /@ {nx, y}]];
Show[{xy, nxy}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

I appreciate any help to see the full leaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
Show[{xy, nxy}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

or use a single `ListLinePlot`

```
ListLinePlot[Join@@(Transpose[Flatten /@ {# x, y}] & /@ {1, -1}), AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

or use `GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]` on `xy` and `Show` it with `xy`:

```
Show[xy, MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}]] &, xy, {1}], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

or plot input data for `xy` with the option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}` and combine the two plots:

```
Show[ListLinePlot[Transpose[Flatten /@ {x, y}], ScalingFunctions -> {#, None}]& /@
   {Identity, "Reverse"}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

All four approaches give

[image]

**Update:** To get filling we need to plot the `{y, x}` pairs with the option `Filling -> Axis` and then use `RotationTransform` on the resulting graphics:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[Join @@ (Transpose[Flatten /@ {y, # x}] & /@ {1, -1}), 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Yellow]
```

[image]

Apply [`RotationTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html) to `llp`:

```
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[90 Degree]] &, llp, {1}], 
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** ***how can I remove the middle line?***

```
llp = ListLinePlot[Transpose[Flatten /@ {y, # x}] & /@ {1, -1}, 
  Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Gray, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Yellow]; 
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[90 Degree]] &, llp, {1}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic,  Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change color? I tried with FillingStyle -> Yellow

Comment: @edwards, please see the update.

Comment: To the last figure, how can I remove the middle line? I use axes -> false but it's still there. I would like the leaf alone, without any axis.

Comment: @edwards, remove `Join@@` and add `PlotStyle->Gray` in definition of `llp`.

Comment: you can also use `llp2 = ListLinePlot[Transpose[Flatten /@ {y, # x}] & /@ {1, -1}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Gray, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> Yellow];
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[90 Degree]] &,
   llp2, {1}], PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Axes -> False]`

Comment: It works but I don't understand what the function of $ \{-1,1\} $ is.

Comment: @edwards, `Transpose[Flatten /@ {y, # x}] & /@ {1, -1}` is short form for `{Transpose[Flatten /@ {y, x}], Transpose[Flatten /@ {y, -x}]}` (the pure function `Transpose[Flatten /@ {y, # x}] &` is applied to `1` and then to `-1`)